# How to login to a network account on a MacBook without network?

Tags: server.app

I currently have a MacBook with Lion (fully updated), using the network account from a Lion Server (also fully updates) and I'm able to login to the network account just fine.

However, when I'm offline (away from my home network), I can't login to my account. **How do I make the MacBook cache the network account login information for posterior offline use?**

I'm able to login at home, put the mac to sleep and use it without any network, but if I reboot it for any reason, I'm locked out (only local accounts are "loggable").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17966994#17966994) in the Apple Support Communities, I'm needed to create a mobile account on my server:

> In Workgroup Manager, select your username in the list of users.
>
> Click the Preferences button.
>
> Click the Mobility button.
>
> Turn it on using your desired settings.

Thanks to [HopelessN00b](https://serverfault.com/users/118258/hopelessn00b) for pointing me to the right direction.